# Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:

Tags: android, flutter

I'm not able to run my Flutter Application using physical devices.

Using Android Emulators worked like a charm but not for physical devices.

I tried using different devices but doesn't work.

Of course I've already installed

```
Google USB Driver, rev 11
```

And also I've set my mobile phone to "USB debugging"

Using Android native project I don't have problem to run on pyshical devices.

Information may you may want to know:

**Android studio version**

```
3.2.1
```

**Flutter & Dart info**

```
channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git Framework
• revision f37c235c32 (4 weeks ago) 
• 2018-09-25 17:45:40 -0400 Engine 
• revision 74625aed32 Tools • Dart 2.1.0-dev.5.0.flutter-a2eb050044
```

**Dart plugin version**

```
181.5656
```

**Flutter plugin version**

```
29.1.1
```

**Error log after running on pyshical device**

```
Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:
error: device still connecting

Launching lib\main.dart on ZY12332K4T in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
error: device still connecting
Unhandled exception:
Exit code 1 from: C:\MySDK\platform-tools\adb -s ZY12332K4T shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
#0      _runWithLoggingSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:351:7)
#1      runCheckedSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:282:10)
#2      AndroidDevice.lastLogcatTimestamp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:500:27)
#3      _AdbLogReader._start (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:668:41)
#4      _runGuarded (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:804:24)
#5      _BroadcastStreamController._subscribe (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:217:7)
#6      _ControllerStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:817:19)
#7      _StreamImpl.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:472:9)
#8      FlutterDevice.startEchoingDeviceLog (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:240:71)
#9      FlutterDevice.runHot (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:283:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     HotRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_hot.dart:262:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     AppDomain.startApp.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:384:62)
#12     AppDomain.launch.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:440:26)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#16     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#17     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#18     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     AppInstance._runInZone (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:811:20)
#20     AppDomain.launch (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:438:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#21     AppDomain.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:381:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#22     RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:277:38)
<asynchronous suspension>
#23     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:372:18)
#24     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#25     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#26     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#27     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
#28     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45)
#29     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
#30     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:476:7)
#31     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#32     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:28:18)
#33     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:295:13)
#34     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
#35     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#36     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#37     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#38     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
#39     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45)
#40     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
#41     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:476:7)
#42     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#43     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:33:20)
#44     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#45     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#46     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#47     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#48     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#49     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#50     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

Comment: have you solve this issues? I have same issues. If you have done then please answer.

Comment: If Anybody is looking for an answer the last one(allow file transfer along with usb debugging) has worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for me was replacing the USB wire. I know it is not the solution you thought but I tried with another USB and worked like a charm.

Moreover, If you have a Samsung mobile, you probably need other things to do:

- Install [Smart Swith - Samsung](https://www.samsung.com/us/smart-switch/)
- Install [Android USB driver for Windows](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows)

Good coding!

Answer (score 6):

Using **USB for file transfer** with **USB debugging** worked for me

**When using USB for charging this device**

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Linux, locale en_IN)
⣻Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:
error: insufficient permissions for device: user in plugdev group; are your udev
rules wrong?
See [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html] for more information



[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

**when using USB for file transfer**

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Linux, locale en_IN)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a temporary fix you can follow the steps in this link https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33938#issuecomment-499250288. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem ,please first end task adb and android studio, emulator so everything.

download this : lextotan.com/platform-tools_r28.0.2-windows.zip

and put your sdk folder file . example: C:/sdk
replace all of files.

open android studio after Tools>Sdk manager>Sdk Tools .
and bottom right select Show Package Details and install 28.0.3(2,1)

Apply and ok. restart your android studio. 
and start ur emulator.
that is all thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just Download this platform-tools and replace it with

C:\Users\User-name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

Windows: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-windows.zip
macOS: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-darwin.zip
Linux: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-linux.zip

Answer (score -1):

The solution for me was closing the IDE and disconnecting the device from computer then connecting it again.